# Make voice over focus from one view controller to another(presented modally) and vice versa

Tags: ios, iphone, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have two view controllers :

```
- UITableViewController
- UIViewController
```

`UIViewController` i present modally over `UITableViewController` which can be swiped to expand (like in iOS Maps app).

Problem is in `Voice-Over`. When it activates, the focus is on `UIViewController`, but left swipe does not take it to `UITableViewController`.

Note: I can interact with UITableViewController in the background when `UIViewController` is presented modally as I pass the touches dropped in `UIViewControllers` transparent area.

Answer (score 1):

According to the way you implemented your view controllers, a quick view to the [`accessibilityElementsHidden`](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#hide-elements) and [`accessibilityViewIsModal`](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18230.html#accessibilityViewIsModal) properties may help.

Take a look at:

- This [article](http://ronnqvi.st/adding-accessible-behavior) in the **Implementing accessible modal views** section to understand the way the latter property works with a clever, interactive and pedagogical illustration.
- These [many useful examples](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#modal-view) including code and illustrations.